# Выключение\перезагрузка

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 11.10Проблема в том, что система совсем никак не реагирует на кнопки выключить, перезагрузить, выйты из системы...То есть, при нажатии на кнопку "Выключить" все продолжает работать как ни в чем не бывало.Выключить и перезагрузить получается только через консоль с помощью sudo reboot и sudo poweroff.

Answer (score 1):

Схожая проблема наблюдалась в обновленной Mandriva, демон akonadi наслаивался на аплет в KDE и клика не происходило. Проверьте настройки действий в графике. Возможно прийдется править "gnome-config", так же могут мешать запущенные процессы имеющие PID выше X-ов или среды.